# Retrieve column of Listview items and display in a comboBox on another form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have 2 forms: 1 form contains a listView and another form contains a comboBox.

I would like the first column of the listView to be loaded into the comboBox on the second form.

This is my attempt:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(Form2.listView2.columnHeader1);
```

However, this does not work. (Form2.ListView is inaccessible due to its protection level). Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: "1 form contains a listView" so `Form2` is your "1 Form" ? is `listView2` static ? or did you name your Variable `Form2` ?

Comment: Form1 has the comboBox. Form2 has the listView. I want the comboBox on Form1 to retrieve the first column of the listView on Form2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution:

Go to the `Properties` of `listView2` in the winforms designer and look for `Modifiers`. Then select `Public` like you see in the picture below:

[image]

And now it will be accessible

The more elegant solution:

Create a property in your first Form which has only a getter. In this getter you can safely return the `columnHeader1`:

```
public ColumnHeader ColumnHeader { get { return this.listView1.Columns["columnHeader1"]; }}
```

or:

```
public ColumnHeader ColumnHeader { get { return this.columnHeader1; }}
```

EDIT:

It seems that you rather would like to have all values from that column. So in this case you would have to return all the values, which can be done like this:

```
public List<string> AlllValuesFromColumn
{
    get
    {
        int indexOfColumn = listView2.Columns.IndexOf(this.columnHeader1);
        return listView2.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>().Select(x => x.SubItems[indexOfColumn].Text).ToList();
    }
}
```

To Add all the values in one blow to the `ComboBox` you can use [AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.addrange?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_ComboBox_ObjectCollection_AddRange_System_Object___):

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(Form2.AlllValuesFromColumn.ToArray());
```

EDIT 2:

But the solution I personally would prefer is to hold the data source in an extra variable. This can be passed around. No magic there.

Answer (score 0):

Make a public method in your second form and let the method set the comboboxitems.

Form1:

```
bool Do = true;
int i = 0;
Form2 F = new Form2();

while (Do)
{
    try
    {
        F.AddItem(listView1.Columns[i].Name);
        i++;
    }

    catch
    {
        Do = false;
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
public void AddItem(string ToAdd)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(ToAdd);
}
```